# Multiple named views with dynamic routing in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

**Edit:**   Here is the complete code at [**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/FWcuBgGpVdMj3CroFrYJ). Though I can not c anything in execution but same code working at local. However gives a console error though

It all works perfect. But due to `:id` in `/news/:id/`, i am getting jquery/angular errors in console which can not be tracked anywhere in my code

I can not c What i am doing wrong.

Edit: Solved plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/FWcuBgGpVdMj3CroFrYJ

Comment: What would you like to achieve? Can you create plunker?

Comment: @irhabi.. Plunker is out there. Achievement is off-course running the app error free with that minimal; structure. Along with headers and dynamic values for news/id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you are trying to use `ui-router` but you're including `ngRoute` script in your plunker. Change it to

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>`

Then everything should work fine!

I suggest you a few changes...

**1. Use `ui-sref` instead of `href`** because it's much easier to define

`ui-sref="post({id:1})"` which turns into `href="#/news/1"`

If you would like to change url some day, then you will have to just change your route file, not each `href`.

`$stateProvider
    .state('post', {
        url: "news/:id"`

or

`$stateProvider
    .state('post', {
        url: "archive/:id"`

or

`$stateProvider
    .state('post', {
        url: "whatever/:id"`

**2. Use abstract state**

In your example it's a way better to define abstract state which holds header, content and footer - it's a typical use case.

> **ui-router**
>   Abstract States
>
> An abstract state can have child states but can not get activated
>   itself. An 'abstract' state is simply a state that can't be
>   transitioned to. It is activated implicitly when one of its
>   descendants are activated.
>
> Some examples of how you might use an abstract state are:
>
> To prepend a url to all child state urls. To insert a template with
>   its own ui-view(s) that its child states will populate. Optionally
>   assign a controller to the template. The controller must pair to a
>   template. Additionally, inherit $scope objects down to children, just
>   understand that this happens via the view hierarchy, not the state
>   hierarchy. To provide resolved dependencies via resolve for use by
>   child states. To provide inherited custom data via data for use by
>   child states or an event listener. To run an onEnter or onExit
>   function that may modify the application in someway. Any combination
>   of the above. Remember: Abstract states still need their own
>    for their children to plug into. So if you are using an
>   abstract state just to prepend a url, set resolves/data, or run an
>   onEnter/Exit function, then you'll additionally need to set template:
>   "".

Here's a `plunker` which shows how I would do it.

https://plnkr.co/edit/5FvJaelyxdl5MuALt5VY?p=preview

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the documentation for [ui router named views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views),

You can use following syntax for using multiple views

```
$stateProvider
  .state('state',{
    url: '',
    views: {
      'header': {
        templateUrl: 'views/header.html',
        controller: 'headerCtrl'
      },
      'content': {
        template: '<div ui-view=" "></div>',  //<-- child templates loaded to here
      },
      'footer': {
        templateUrl: 'views/footer.html',
        controller: 'footerCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('state.post', {
    url: 'news/:id/:KeyWords'
    templateUrl: 'views/post.html'   //<-- This goes into content's ui-view
  });
```

I'm guessing you want to keep the `header` and `footer` and change `content` views.

You can achieve this by making this state as parent to all other states

suppose

```
.state('main',{
  abstract: true,
  views: {
    'header': ... ,
    'content': {
       template: '<ui-view></ui-view>',
    }
    'footer': ...
  }
})
```

then all the child views will load their views in the , 
ex: in `main.child` etc, your template will load in the content's `<ui-view></ui-view>` tag

Comment: check the syntax properly, you are using `val` key. where does it fit?

Comment: see my edit, using content view as placeholder you can load child route's templates in `<ui-view>`

Comment: @Vamsi can you plz run recently edited code in plunker for him. Its complete code..

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use a custom template depending on keywords you can do the following:

`.config(['$routeProvider',
      function($routeProvider, $routeParams) {
         $routeProvider
            .when('/news/:id/:keyWords', {
               template: '<div ng-include="url"></div>',
               controller: "exampleController"
            })`

then in the exampleController

`function($routeParams, $scope) {
    $scope.url = $routeParams.keyWords;
}`

Comment: I want to use state